# Will one class method that creates a loop stop another in python?

Tags: python

So here's my code since it will probably make more sense than my question:

```
class Actuator:

    current = 50

    def __init__(self, pin_out):
        #do initialization stuff
    def actuatorOut():
        while self.current <=99:
            self.current += 1
            pwm_library_method(pin=pin_out,actuator_distance=self.current)
    def actuatorIn():
        while self.current >=1:
            self.current-=1
            pwm_library_method(pin=pin_out,actuator_distance=self.current)
```

Now I want to know, if I call Actuator.actuatorOut() then call Actuator.In(), will Actuator.In() break the first method call's loop? If not, how is this done?

Comment: Until the loop finishes, *nothing* will happen, as the function won't return control to the caller to call anything else.

Comment: Extending on @jonrsharpe 's comment, if you have two threads poking at the same method, they would in theory cause both to not return because one would add and the other subtract, and then you also don't have Locks to guard the critical section (the place where result is assigned) so your code basically isn't going to do what you think you want to do.

Comment: Why do you use loops at all in those methods? Fading in / out, for a smooth transition?

Comment: A little background info: the system is for face tracking, a monitor will turn to a face up and down. Right now we have an algorithm telling us when a face is above or below the center of the screen. I'd like to extend the actuator when y>center and retract it when y<center. How could I accomplish this? Should I avoid using classes for this?

Comment: Lukas, the actuator takes a voltage in from 0 to 3 V. We can use PWM to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want those two methods running concurrently. You would use [threading](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/threading.html) and then a shared data structure like [Queue](http://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html)

Comment: Thank you Ben, this appears to be the answer I was looking for.

Comment: After reading your background info you might actually not want to do this. If you only have one actuator and therefore can only go up or down not both at the same time then you should probably just have a method that calls in or out based on conditions. You could probably even simplify each of those to be if instead of while and then a main controlling loop decide up or down each loop.